# Где я зашел в бесконечный цикл?

Tags: c, строки

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 20

int main(){
    char M[N], M2[N];
    int i,j;
    gets(M);
    for(i=0; M2[i] !='\0';i++){
        M2[i]=' ';
    }
    M2[0]=M[0];
    for (i=0; M[i] != '\0'; i++){
        char n = M[i];              
        for (j=0; j=i; j++){
            if (n!=M[j]){
                M2[j]=n;
            }else{
                for(int u=j;M[u]!='\0';u++){
                    M[u]=M[u+1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (i=0; M2[i] != '\0';i++) {
        printf ("%c", M2[i]);
    }
}
```

Когда запускаю код, компилятор зацикливается. По заданию нужно переписать строку без повторяющихся символов.

Comment: У вас уже первый же цикл не имеет смысла, так как массив M2 не инициализирован.

Comment: в самом вложенном цикле идет проход по переменной u, но при этом проверка по переменной j

Comment: Может быть вы попали в бесконечный цикл, в строке for (j=0; j=i; j++){, где вы вместо проверки условия осуществляете присваивание.

Comment: Учитесь пользоваться отладчиком, он в таких случаях помогает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция `gets` является не безопасной, и больше не поддерживается стандартом C. Вместо нее лучше использовать функцию `fgets`.

Данный цикл

```
    for(i=0; M2[i] !='\0';i++){
        M2[i]=' ';
    }
```

бессмысленен, так как массив `M2` не был инициализирован.

В данном цикле у вас имеет место присвоение вместо сравнения

```
for (j=0; j=i; j++){
          ^^^^
```

К тому же последующее предложение `if-else` не имеет смысла.

Программа может выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N   20

int main(void) 
{
    char s1[N];
    char s2[N];

    printf( "Enter a string no more than %d characters: ", N );
    fgets( s1, N, stdin );

    s1[strcspn( s1, "\n" )] = '\0';

    size_t i = 0;
    size_t j = 0;

    do
    {
        size_t k = 0;
        while ( k < j && s1[i] != s2[k] ) k++;

        if ( k == j )
        {
            s2[j++] = s1[i];
        }
    } while ( s1[i++] );

    puts( s2 );

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль может иметь вид

```
Enter a string no more than 20 characters: AABBCCCDEFGGHHH
ABCDEFGH
```

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю зачем там столько циклов и вообще столько кода? Вот пример в виде отдельной функции 
`size_t strcpy_norep(const char * s_in, char * s_out, size_t s_out_size){
 char c, c_prev = 0, *ptr=s_out;
 while((c = *s_in++) ) if(c!=c_prev) *ptr++=(c_prev=c); 
 *ptr = 0;
 return ptr-s_out;
}`

Comment: @ДмитрийЕвгеньевичХоличев Ваша функция рассматривает только смежные символы, тогда как я представил функцию, которая записывает только уникальные символы в результирующую строку. Из вопроса не ясно, какой именно из этих подходов требуется. Хотя из представленного в вопросе кода, скорей всего следует, что требуется мой подход, хотя я могу ошибаться.

Comment: вполне возможно вы,

Comment: ... правы. Но и тогда зачем там столько циклов? Есть же функции strchr и memchr, вот например как то так: ` int c;
 char s[60] = "\0", *ptr = s, *ptr_end = s + sizeof(s)-1;
 while((c=getchar())!='\n'){
  if(!strchr(s, c)){
   *ptr++=c; *ptr = 0;
   if(ptr>=ptr_end){
    printf("\noverflow, max char count; %d\n", sizeof(s)-1);
    break;
   } 
  }
 }
 printf("'%s'\n", s);`
Только если по условию задания использовать strchr и memchr нельзя, но такое условие лишено смысла даже в при обучении,  зачем учить "изобретать велосипеды"?

Answer (score 4):

1) В строчке `for (j = 0; j=i; j++)` поменяйте условие проверки на `j<i`.

2) (замечание) Если пишете на Си, то лучше делайте объявление переменных-счетчиков циклов вне инструкции цикла. Это я про самый вложенный цикл со счетчиком `int u=j` говорю. Все-таки, это плюсовая тенденция больше. Также, как отметили в комментариях, используйте отладчик, чтобы проверять значения переменных на каждой итерации, а именно рекомендую разобраться, что такое breakpoint и с чем его едят. Например, в MSVS очень удобно, на мой взгляд, реализована данная деталь. Также, для начала можете там использовать команды типа "шаг с заходом", "шаг с обходом" и проч. В таких задачах очень помогает.

Answer (score 2):

Вот здесь

```
   for (j=0; j=i; j++){
```

уже при `i = 1`

Answer (score 1):

Сделал сам вот таким образом:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 20

int main(){
    char M[N];
    int i,j,u,k=0;
    gets(M);

    for (i=0; M[i]!='\0'; i++){
        char n = M[i];              
        for (j=i+1; M[j]!='\0'; j++){
            if (n==M[j]){
                k++;
                for(u=j; M[u]!='\0'; u++){
                    M[u]=M[u+1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (i=0; M[i] != '\0';i++) {
        printf ("%c", M[i]);
    }
    printf ("\nKol-vo udalennyh symbols is = %i", k);
}
```

Так будет верно же?

Comment: Вы задали вопрос. Вам на него ответили. Не надо в ответах задавать новые вопросы. Это вводит в заблуждение читающих вопрос. Если у вас появился новый вопрос, то создайте для него новую тему.